# Get all methods on an Type[] of interfaces using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find all the methods that an interface grants me through reflection. I have a type array which I verify has only interfaces, from there I need to extract all the methods.Unfortunately, If I do something like typeof(IList).GetMethods() it only returns the methods on IList not those on ICollection, or IEnumerable
I've tried the following linq query but it doesn't return the methods found on the outer interfaces. How can I fix my query?

```
from outerInterfaces in interfaces
from i in outerInterfaces.GetInterfaces()   
from m in i.GetMethods()
select m
```

If this was SQL I could do something like a recursive CTE with a union all, but I don't think such a syntax exist in C#. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
 typeof(IList<>).GetMethods().Concat(typeof(IList<>)
                .GetInterfaces()
                .SelectMany(i => i.GetMethods()))
                .Select(m => m.Name)
                .ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

EDIT: Response to the comments.

Tested it with this code:

```
    public interface IFirst
    {
        void First();
    }

    public interface ISecond : IFirst
    {
        void Second();
    }

    public interface IThird :ISecond
    {
        void Third();
    }

    public interface IFourth : IThird
    {
        void Fourth();
    }
```

Test code:

```
        typeof(IFourth).GetMethods().Concat(typeof(IFourth)
            .GetInterfaces()
            .SelectMany(i => i.GetMethods()))
            .Select(m => m.Name)
            .ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

And the output is:

```
Fourth
Third
Second
First
```

Comment: @LukeH: See my edit. GetInterfaces() gets all the interfaces and walks up the hierarchy tree for you.

Comment: @LukeH: Wow, I never knew that. I'd love to see some documentation around that. I also wonder if other languages (most notably VB.Net) do that as well...

Comment: @BFree: I just deleted my comment while I do some more research. I'm less than certain about it, although I'm sure I read it somewhere authoritative. Having said that, I think `GetInterfaces` is recursive anyway which would make the actual behaviour irrelevant to your answer.

Comment: @LukeH: I guess an easy way to test your theory would be to create a couple of interfaces at runtime using TypeBuilder and then see what the output would be. Hm.... I'll try that when I get a chance...

Comment: @BFree: I can't find any sources to back me up, but I just did a quick test: `interface ITest : IList<int>`, created in C#, has `IList<int>`, `ICollection<int>`, `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable` as explicit base interfaces when viewed in Reflector; `Interface ITest Inherits IList(Of Integer)`, created in VB, shows `IList<int>` as its only explicit base interface. Using `GetInterfaces` on either version seems to return the full hierarchy of base interfaces.

Comment: @LukeH: Wow, that's awesome. Learn something new every day. Thanks for the effort in researching that.

Comment: @BFree: No problem. Although I think this info makes no practical difference to your answer (or anything else for that matter). A type implements all of its base interfaces whether they're explicitly declared or not, and the reflection API also appears to always return all base interfaces whether they're explicitly declared or not.

Comment: @LukeH: Which begs the question, why DOES C# do it? And then why does VB.Net NOT do it?

Answer (score 4):

There's no "built-in" LINQ recursion (that I'm aware of), but you can create a boilerplate LINQ extension to get all descendants:  (warning: compiled in notepad)

```
static public class RecursionExtensions
{
    static public IEnumerable<T> AllDescendants<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                                Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> descender)
    {
        foreach (T value in source)
        {
            yield return value;

            foreach (T child in descender(value).AllDescendants<T>(descender))
            {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this, treating the base types a descendant nodes in a tree:

```
  from ifaceType in interfaces.AllDescendants( t => t.GetInterfaces())
```

Given that you can compose your method selector:

```
from ifaceType in interfaces.AllDescendants( t=> t.GetInterfaces())
from m in ifaceType.GetMethods()
select m
```

which should give you all methods in all interfaces in the `interfaces` collection, plus all base interfaces